# How to redirect my root domain to a www domain that is in Azure premium frontdoor?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

How to redirect my root domain to a www domain that is in Azure premium frontdoor?

Example:

My root domain: csonline.com

My Frontdoor custom Domain: [ www.csonline.com ]

I have created custom domain and added that records to the public dns. When i google [www.csonline.com](http://www.csonline.com) page is loading but if i google http://csonline.com or https://csonline.com thorowing error as DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eRgx.png)

Comment: To redirect a root domain to a www domain in Azure Premium Front Door, add a CNAME record for your root domain that points to your Front Door [profile](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain.md). Azure Front Door supports apex domains but requires special considerations. Use alias records in Azure DNS to point a zone apex record to an Azure Front Door profile with public endpoints.

Comment: Mapping your apex or root domain to your Azure Front Door profile involves CNAME flattening, sometimes called DNS chasing. Use the Azure portal to onboard an apex domain on your Azure Front Door and enable HTTPS by associating it with a TLS [certificate](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/frontdoor/front-door-how-to-onboard-apex-domain.md).

Comment: to-onboard-apex-domain.md). 
To validate a domain, create a DNS TXT record. The name of the TXT record must be in the form _dnsauth.{subdomain}. Azure Front Door provides a unique value for your TXT record when you begin adding the domain to Azure Front [Door](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/frontdoor/apex-domain.md).

Answer (score 1):

Steps to redirect your root domain to a www domain that is in Azure premium frontdoor:

[image]

- code reference from [git](https://github.com/MGodfrey50/Shared-Code/blob/master/RootRedirect.txt)
- Add a CNAME record for your root domain that points to Front Door [profile](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/internet-peering/walkthrough-exchange-all.md).
  [image]
- Use Azure DNS for Azure Front Door endpoints to enable CNAME flattening or DNS [chasing](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/load-balancer/basic/quickstart-basic-public-load-balancer-portal.md).
  [image]
- Validate the domain by creating a DNS TXT record. The name of the TXT record must be of the form `_dnsauth.{subdomain}.` Azure Front Door provides a unique value for your TXT record when you start to add the domain to Azure Front [Door](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/load-balancer/basic/quickstart-basic-public-load-balancer-portal.md).
  [image]
- Associate your apex domain with a TLS certificate to enable [HTTPS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/internet-peering/walkthrough-peering-service-all.md).

[image]

- Use an Azure Front Door-managed certificate, Azure Front Door attempts to automatically rotate (renew) the certificate.

> Before it does so, Azure Front Door checks whether the DNS CNAME record is still pointed to the Azure Front Door endpoint. Apex domains don't have a CNAME record pointing to an Azure Front Door endpoint, so the auto-rotation for managed certificate fails until the domain ownership is [revalidated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/apex-domain).